# setAttribute not changed value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have three elements and I am trying setAttribute for each element:

```
const foldable = document.getElementsByClassName('foldable')
let result = Array.from(foldable)
result.forEach(i => {
 i.onclick = () => {
  i.getAttribute('isClicked') 
   ? i.setAttribute('isClicked', false)
   : i.setAttribute('isClicked', true)
 }
})
```

if isClicked have value as true, isClicked should be false, else if isClicked have value as false isClicked should be true, but it is working only once. If isClicked equals false, isClicked is not changing to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your ternary operator to following

```
(i.getAttribute('isClicked') === "true")
   ? i.setAttribute('isClicked', false)
   : i.setAttribute('isClicked', true)
```

Because, in case of attribute being **false**, `i.getAttribute('isClicked')` will give a string `"false"` which is evaluated as **true**.

Comment: The string "false" is also evaluated as true in an if statement. getAttribute returns a string